# Numerical solution of coupled dif eq

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

So I have a set of 3 differentialequations I want to solve.  They can be seen in my code.  My problem, is that I want to combine these codes so that I can have a for loop with respect to R (as will be shown.

What I have:

```
T2 = 1;
[T,Y] = ode45(@ball, [0 5*T2] ,[0 0 -10]);
figure
plot(T,Y(:,1),'-r',T,Y(:,2),'-g',T,Y(:,3),'-b')
legend('x(t)','y(t)','z(t)')
xlabel('Time (in units of T2)')
title(['Plot for RT2 = ',num2str(R)])
```

Where the @ball is

```
`function dr = ball(t,b)

T2 = 1;
T1 = T2/2;
d  = 0;
R  = 0.2;

dr = zeros(3,1);
dr(1) = (-1/T2)*b(1)-d*b(2);
dr(2) = (-1/T2)*b(2) + d*b(1) + R*b(3);
dr(3) = (-1/T1)*b(3) - R*b(2) ;

end`
```

What I want is a single program that will do this, but allow me to include a for loop so I can vary R and make a couple subplots.  IS this possible?

Comment: ``[T,Y] = ode45(@ball, [0 5*T2] ,[0 0 -10],[], R);`` in the function call and changing your function to ``function dr = ball(t,b,R)`` (removing ``R = 0.2``; in the function) should also do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an anonymous function for this.

Change `ball.m` to remove the hard-coded `R` and replace it with an input argument:

```
function dr = ball(t,b,R)

T2 = 1;
T1 = T2/2;
d  = 0;
%// etc.
```

and then replace your `ode45` call with this:

```
R=0.4;
[T,Y] = ode45(@(t,b) ball(t,b,R), [0 5*T2] ,[0 0 -10]);
```

where `@(t,b) ball(t,b,R)` is a function with inputs `t` and `b` that calls `ball.m` with the value of `R` specified on the previous line. So you can construct the `for` loop as follows:

```
for R=0.2:.02:1 %// or whatever range you want
    [T,Y] = ode45(@(t,b) ball(t,b,R), [0 5*T2] ,[0 0 -10]);
    %// etc.
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the usage of an anonymous function (which is a decent way to get your result done), you can also pass the argument directly in the `ode45`-call. After the initial condition the next argument are the options, which can be left empty. After the options, additional Parameters can be submitted:

```
function main

T2 = 1;
opt = []; % // no further options
R = 0.2; % // the parameter R to give to the function ball
[T,Y] = ode45(@ball, [0 5*T2] ,[0 0 -10], opt, R); %% // added opt and R as parameter
figure
plot(T,Y(:,1),'-r',T,Y(:,2),'-g',T,Y(:,3),'-b')
legend('x(t)','y(t)','z(t)')
xlabel('Time (in units of T2)')
title(['Plot for RT2 = ',num2str(R)])

end


function dr = ball(t,b, R)

T2 = 1;
T1 = T2/2;
d  = 0;
% R  = 0.2; % // not needed anymore

dr = zeros(3,1);
dr(1) = (-1/T2)*b(1)-d*b(2);
dr(2) = (-1/T2)*b(2) + d*b(1) + R*b(3);
dr(3) = (-1/T1)*b(3) - R*b(2) ;

end
```